# Google Container Engine REST API Authorization

Tags: google-authentication, google-kubernetes-engine

As mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/v1beta1/authorizing) I created API key for using [cluster operations](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/clusters/operations).

For example for this query:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/container/v1beta1/projects/PROJECT_ID/clusters
```

And as mentioned

> After you have an API key, your application can append the query
>   parameter key=yourAPIKey to all request URLs.

I added it to url:

https://www.googleapis.com/container/v1beta1/projects/PROJECT_ID/clusters?key=my_key

But i have error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

I even tried to add key to Authorization part of header...and had this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Where is problem? Or did i something wrong?

Comment: Which type of API key did you create (server, browser, android, or iOS)?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Google help documentation for API Keys](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/?hl=en_US#usingkeys) (emphasis added):

> An API key (either a server key or a browser key) is a unique
>   identifier that you generate using the Developers Console. Using an
>   API key does not require user action or consent. API keys do not grant
>   access to any account information, and **are not used for
>   authorization**.

Furthermore, it says that they can be used to access data that is public or owned by a Google service. The Google Container Clusters (GKE) data is neither of these. I'm not sure why the documentation suggests using an API key, but I know that OAuth works so if you can use that instead you should be able to get the REST API working.

Comment: I have same issue. How OAuth works? can you please provide more details?