# How to use OAuth2.0 to authorize Google Container Engine APIs

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to make a call using the Google Container Engine API via my browser.  I have created both a client ID and the public API access key.

When I try to use the public API access key, I always get unuauthorized:

https://www.googleapis.com/container/v1beta1/projects/cohesive-feat-92204/clusters?fields=clusters%2FmasterAuth&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
(where XXXXX... is my key)

Is there a document that describes all the required values for the call?  How you specify the client ID and the client secret etc...where you put in the scope, etc...

This link https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/v1beta1/libraries gives me a 404

Answer (score 0):

This is the same question as [Google Container Engine REST API Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28718370/google-container-engine-rest-api-authorization/) and the answer is that a public API access key cannot be used to access the Google Container Engine API.

Comment: Fine, if you can't use the Rest API Authorization.  But you should be able to structure a REST call with the OAuth fields.  That is the second part of my question.

Comment: There is probably a client library for your language that will do this for you -- see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#libraries. If you want to do it yourself, you need to set an Authorization header with an access token (e.g. https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/token.go#L68). You get a short-lived access token by passing an authorization code or refresh token to the Google OAuth2 endpoint (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token).

Comment: Hi, @RobertBailey! can you help me by taking a look at this question, please!                                                                                           https://stackoverflow.com/q/47149954/7644562